# Is Shiva not freed of sin?

Tags: shiva, shatapatha-brahmana

I found a verse in shatpath brahman:-

> “Pragâpati said to him [Rudra], 'My boy, why do you cry, when you are born out of labor and trouble?' He said, 'Nay, but **I am not freed from sin;** I have no name given me: give me a name!' Hence one should give a name to the boy that is born, for thereby one frees him from evil;--even a second, even a third (name), for thereby one frees him from evil time after time” - (Satapatah Brahmana 6:1:3:9)

### Is Shiva sinful?

Comment: According to the Shvetasvatara upanishad, Rudra/Shiva is brahman/Ishwara. So Shiva is free from sin. As for your particular quotation, it looks like an allegory/arthavAda to show the importance of giving a name to a new born.

Comment: Sri Rudram from the Yajurveda says - 

yā te rudra śivā tanūraghorā'pāpakāśinī,
tayā nastanuvā śantamayā giriśaṁtābhicākaśīhi.

Rudra! That blessed and benign form of Thine, which obliterates the trace of all sins—....

If Rudra/Shiva's form can remove all sins, then Rudra/Shiva himself must be free from sin.

Comment: @iwill Could you please convert your comments into an answer?

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion:  I think in this brAhmana, it was stated in esoteric sense, with Agni himself Prajapati and Kumara

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion That's okay. You can update your answer later.

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion: I will wait for your answer :-)

Comment: @Iwillcloseyourquestion Great! I hope you get your laptop soon. :)

Comment: Yes, he is not freed of sin just as that verse says.

Comment: No he is not free of sin every for creature in this universe obeys the law of karma.

Comment: @Wikash Shiva is god and law of karma is only for humans.

Comment: Shiva though an exalted deity is also a jivatma like all of us. Hence he is also subject to karma and can accumulate both sins and punyas. This is as per the Vaishnavas.

Comment: @Pandya: Thanks for keeping my answer in dormant State.:-) I will update it later

Comment: No Shiva also can accumulate karma. At one point he even hides from Shani.